# How to configure and read logs in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

i want to read my mysql database log for each updation on every row (CRUD), Can anyone tell me how to configure and read the mysql log for each query operation ? please help

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your mysql-server version. Have a look at the appropriate version of this document: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply,but i could not find deleted query log, suppose if i delete any row,how the log will be configured, and can i read the log using java ?